# how to detect daily first launch in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

we can detect first Launch of our app using NSUserdefaults. But is there any way to detect daily first launch in iOS ? I need to show a popup daily one at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you guys! got an easy solution. Thanks for the support

```
  let today = NSDate().formatted 
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(Constants.FIRSTLAUNCH) == today)
    {
         //Already Launched today
    }
    else
    {
         //Today's First Launch
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(today, forKey:Constants.FIRSTLAUNCH)
    }

extension NSDate {
var formatted: String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    return  formatter.stringFromDate(self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // get the time the app last launched
    let lastLaunch = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("lastLaunch")
    let lastLaunchDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: lastLaunch)
    // check to see if lastLaunchDate is today.
    let lastLaunchIsToday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday(lastLaunchDate)

    if !lastLaunchIsToday {
        // do your stuff, show a popup or whatever
    }
    // update the last launch value
    NSUserDefaults.setDouble(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970(), forKey: "lastLaunch")
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at appDelegate launch when it is first launch save timestamp to userdefaults or somewhere, then if there is timestamp just check if the date today is different than this date from timestamp, if it is replace old timestamp and show popup

Answer (score 0):

I hope it could help you:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let timestamp = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey(forKey: "lastLaunch")

        if !NSDate.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: timestamp).isToday() {
            // Show popup
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: "lastLaunch")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }

        return false
}

extension NSDate {
    func isToday() -> Bool {
        let today = NSDate()
        self.compare(today)
        let todayCalendar: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Era, .Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: today)
        let selfCalendar: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Era, .Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: self)

        return todayCalendar.day == selfCalendar.day && todayCalendar.month == selfCalendar.month && todayCalendar.year == selfCalendar.year && todayCalendar.era == selfCalendar.era
    }
}
```